# Getting JQuery Stopwatch Run In Background via Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, background, stopwatch

Well I made a stopwatch in JQuery, originally for my website, and then I wanted it to be a chrome extension for a variety of reasons. Anyway it runs fine except one problem. You start it, then as soon as the popup window closes it stops, and I'm having a pain trying to figure out how to fix this.

You can download the source here - http://officialspeed.tk/timesamurai/chrome/stopwatch.zip

**Manifest**

```
{
    "name": "TimeSamurai",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "description": "A very simple stopwatch with a very nice oriental theme added to it.",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/32x32.png",
        "default_title": "TimeSamurai",
        "background_page": "background.html",
        "popup": "popup.html"
   },

    "icons": {
        "16": "images/16x16.png",
        "32": "images/32x32.png",
        "48": "images/48x48.png"
   }
}
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    min-width:350px;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');
    background-position:top left;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-repeat:repeat;}

.display {
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-33px;
    font-size:18;
    font-family:times new roman;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:FFFFFF;
    z-index:1;}

.base {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -117px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width:235px;}

.start {
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-115px;
    width:65px;
    height:33px;
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('images/start.png');}

.start:hover {
    width:65px;
    height:33px;
    color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('images/starthover.png');}

.stop {
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-115px;
    width:65px;
    height:33px;
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('images/stop.png');}

.stop:hover {
    width:65px;
    height:33px;
    color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('images/stophover.png');}

.reset {
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-115px;
    width:65px;
    height:32px;
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('images/reset.png');}

.reset:hover {
    width:65px;
    height:32px;
    color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url('images/resethover.png');}
```

**background.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.stopwatch = function() {
        var clock = $(this);
        var timer = 0;

        clock.addClass('stopwatch');

        // We have to do some searching, so we'll do it here, so we only have to do it once.
        var h = clock.find('.hr');
        var m = clock.find('.min');
        var s = clock.find('.sec');
        var milli = clock.find('.mil');
        var start = clock.find('.start');
        var stop = clock.find('.stop');
        var reset = clock.find('.reset')

        stop.hide();

        start.bind('click', function() {
            timer = setInterval(do_time, 15);
            stop.show();
            start.hide();
        });

        stop.bind('click', function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = 0;
            start.show();
            stop.hide();
        });

        reset.bind('click', function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = 0;
            h.html("00");
            m.html("00");
            s.html("00");
            milli.html("00");
            stop.hide();
            start.show();
        });

        function do_time() {
            // parseInt() doesn't work here...
            hour = parseFloat(h.text());
            minute = parseFloat(m.text());
            second = parseFloat(s.text());
            millisecond = parseFloat(milli.text());

            millisecond++;

            if(millisecond > 59) {
                millisecond = 0;
                second = second + 1;
            }
            if(second > 59) {
                second = 0;
                minute = minute + 1;
            }
            if(minute > 59) {
                minute = 0;
                hour = hour + 1;
            }

            h.html("0".substring(hour >= 10) + hour);
            m.html("0".substring(minute >= 10) + minute);
            s.html("0".substring(second >= 10) + second);
            milli.html("0".substring(millisecond >= 10) + millisecond);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $('#timer').stopwatch();
});
</script>
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="base">
        <img src="images/base.png">
        <div id="timer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post some of the source? Your download link isn't available.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention, cause the site I use to host my website you gotta view officialspeed.tk and then go to officialspeed.tk/timesamurai/chrome/stopwatch.zip to download the file.

Anyway the source is up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you need a [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html).

> A common need for extensions is to
>   have a single long-running script to
>   manage some task or state. Background
>   pages to the rescue.

In your extension, you would use your background page to store and manage the current state of your stopwatch, and the popup page to display any UI/progress.

There's several ways of communicating between scripts. You can use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to talk between your popup.html/background.html or use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` which returns the dom window object of the background page.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I'm still having trouble getting this to run in the background. The reply are incredibly helpful, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong now. Can you help bro?